# How to trigger a element to fadeIn first when a element is visible?

Tags: jquery, fadein

Lets say I have the div `#this-div` in a footer like this.

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div id="this-div">
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    background:black;
}

#this-div {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:none;
}
```

And then I fadeIn #this-div with jQuery like this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
$( '#this-div' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
});
```

But now. Lets say I got alot of content on my website and the footer is a few scrolls down. How can I trigger the fadeIn at first when `<footer>` is visible on the screen?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ao1mfs9/

Comment: [For your animation needs](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

Comment: could use `Waypoints` https://www.google.de/search?q=waypoints.js?

Comment: waypoints.js looks interesting. But is there no way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: After taking a closer look I will probably do this with waypoint.js. But I can find anywhere what licence waypoints.js is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you need to find out the `offset` of your footer like this:

```
var footerTop = $('footer').offset().top;
```

Then, when the viewport reaches that distance from the top of the screen as the user scrolls, you can trigger your *`fadeIn`* effect as such:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this)).scrollTop() >= footerTop){ // adding a little more to the footerTop's value may give a better feeling.
        $( '#this-div' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
    }
});
```